# How can I auto generate date based on number of contacts in a company?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 50,000 row spreadsheet with information such as company, names and dates. Every company has a starting date of 4/8/15 and successive entries in the date column (within each company) are 14 days apart. So person 1 has a date of 4/8/15 while person 2 has a date of 4/22/15 and so forth.

Does anyone know how to generate the dates automatically for each person in a company so that I won't have to do it manually?

```
Company            name         date
ACME USA           person 1     4/8/2015
ACME USA           person 2     4/22/2015
ACME USA           person 3     5/6/2015
ACME USA           person 4     5/20/2015
Fake Company 1     person 1     4/8/2015
Fake Company 1     person 2     4/22/2015
Fake Company 1     person 3     5/6/2015
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s fairly easy.  Assuming that your columns are `A`, `B`, and `C`,
your headers are in row 1, and the data start in row 2, put

```
=IF(A1=A2, C1+14, DATEVALUE("4/8/2015"))
```

into cell `C2` and drag down. 
It says, if the company name on this row (`A2`)
equals the company name on the previous row (`A1`),
then this is *not* the first row for this company,
so we should use the date from the previous row (`C1`) plus 14 (days). 
Otherwise, the company names are different,
so this *is* the first row for this company, so we should use 4/8/2015. 
You’ll need to format column `C` as “date”.