# Excel Excel add to sheet two based off of cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok I'll try my best to explain this. I have my totals all set up for my electrical fittings on sheet 1. I would like to be able to take my entire excel spread sheet from my estimating program, place it on sheet two and have the totals go to their appropriate cells. For example. When I put my totals on sheet 2. I would like column A to see 3/4"conduit and take the total of column B 55ft and place it on Sheet 1 in  the 3/4" totals cell. The only problem is everytime I use sheet 2 the parts and pieces will be in different orders so it has to be by name not designated cell. Thanks and I hope someone has an answer

Comment: I suppose you know your spreadsheets in detail, so your explanation makes sense to you, but you'll have to reformulate it for people who never saw you spreadsheets if you want your question answered.

Comment: Sheet 1

A.                          B.          
3/4 conduit.           Sheet 2 totals
3/4 coupling.        
3/4 connector.       

Sheet 2
A.                            B
3/4 coupling.           5
3/4 conduit.             8
3/4 connector.         10

Comment: i would like column 2b on sheet 2 to recognize a WORD and then take the total of 2c and place it on sheet 1 in the totals column  With the matching Word.

Comment: I understand exactly what your up to, BUT the question really isn't answerable at this point.  I would suggest screenshots might help.

Comment: Don't put pieces of your question into comments; [edit] your question to clarify it.  If you can't post screenshots, type in representations of your sheets, as was done [here](http://superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/892744/150988).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this should work.

The formula would go on sheet 1 column b =sumif(Sheet2!A1:A3,A1,Sheet2!B1:B3)

**Sheet 1: A** | **B**
3/4 conduit | =sumif(sheet2!A1:A3,A1,Sheet2!B1:B3)

**Sheet 2: A** | **B**
3/4 coupling| 5
3/4 conduit | 8
3/4 connector| 10

Sheet 1: B1 should = 8