# Using filter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel file which contains details of all the school students from A to Z. Out of it, in a separate sheet created `FEES DUE FORM` for each class that contains only `ROLL NO.`, `NAME` from APR '14 through MAR '16 in each column to put check mark if a student has paid fees for particular month.

I have to print form for each class separately. I want it to be in the below format -

```
SCHOOL NAME
FEES DUE LIST 2015-16
CLASS : [Here I want to update automatically the class which I filtered.]
ROLL NO. Name Apr 15 May 15 Jun 15  ...  Mar 16
```

The rest comes easily in filtering, how to do it?

Comment: Can you rewrite what you want more clearly? You may use screenshot or upload an example file for easier understanding

Comment: If you can’t post screenshots, type in representations of your sheets, as was done [here](http://superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/892744/150988).

Comment: What would be helpful would be representations of the ***input data*** and the ***output data***, not just the headers.  You don't need to post actual sensitive data — in fact, **please don't** — just make up fake data, like Andy, Barbara, Charlie, Debbie, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine all your separate Class sheets into a single Table on a single sheet, with an added column for Class.

Then you can use the table filter buttons to filter by class.

The single table also makes it easy to generate other reports eg by student, or by any other available column.