# Excel Budget Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a very nuanced budget in Excel. I have a lot of rules about budgeting and thought it would be easier to create a spreadsheet. When a certain line item exceeds budget it is to borrow from another specific line item. Once the 1st line item=0 then it is to stop borrowing. All I know how to do is =IF(n4<0,n4-j9) But if J9 is greater than the amount N4 is negative, how do I get it to stop borrowing funds?

Okay just to try and help explain... Say n4 is positive, then no borrowing from J9 should happen; however, if N4 is say negative 1000, and j9 has $500, then I want N4 to borrow it all. If N4 were negative 1000 and J9 had $2000, then I'd only want it to borrow $1000 and also, later when N4 is positive I'd like to have N4 return the funds to J9 lol. I'm wondering if I can use hidden cells to perform some of the functions or if there is something like nested "IF" functions that would do the trick.

Do you understand what I'm trying to do now?

Comment: It would be easier for people to answer if you provide a screenshot (include a link in a comment to a sharing site like imgur.com), or include a mockup in the question, or at least define all of the involved cells.

Comment: Are you asking what functionality a nuanced budget spreadsheet should have, or are you asking how to implement certain functionality in Excel?  If it’s the first one, your question is an accounting question rather than a computer question, and therefore is off-topic for Super User.  If you’re asking how to implement certain functionality in Excel, you need to describe the desired functionality much more clearly.  Post sample data, indicating which cells are raw data that you enter, and which ones you want Excel to compute,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  explaining the rules for that computation (what you have now is a good start, but it’s not enough).  You don’t need to post screenshots — in fact, it’s better if you don’t.  Just type in representations of your sheets, as was done [here](http://superuser.com/q/889201/354511) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/892744/354511).  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=IF(n4>0,IF((n4-j9)>=0,n4-j9,"error"),"error")
```

But without really being able to see some data or a better explanation, I don't think we can help much.

You can also change `"error"` to `0` or …