# How can I make the value of one cell change, based on the value of another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am writing an inventory list for my office, which is combined with a borrow list. What I want to do, is change the number of items in the inventory list, once an item has been borrowed. For instance, if I have 2 hard drives listed on stock, I want the spreadsheet to automatically decrement that value, when I enter that data in the borrow list. Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Do you really, *really* need to ***change*** the value in the spreadsheet, or is it good enough to *display* the adjusted value?  Hint: the latter is much easier.

Comment: I'm not really sure which one will be better, to be honest. I will edit the post with a link to the file, because I have the feeling I haven't asked my question properly.

Comment: People are reluctant to download and open files from unknown people because of the risk of malware.  It would be better if you would just describe your problem more clearly.  It might help if you type in a textual representation of your spreadsheet, as was done [here](http://superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/892744/150988), reducing the data to the bare minimum necessary to illustrate/illuminate your question.  And if you don’t need to change the value in the spreadsheet, I suggest that you focus on finding a way to *display* the adjusted value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the `COUNTIF()` function would be useful. You can use it
to count how many cells in a range match some value. Say an inventory ID
is in A1, borrowed item IDs are in G1:G20, and you want B1 to say how
many of A1 were borrowed. I don't have Excel on this machine, but
something like this in B1:

```
=COUNTIF($G$1:$G$20,A1)
```

Comment: This looks like its gonna help, but does this function also change the value of A1? I'll try to upload a mockup file of what I have done till now, To clarify better on what im trying to achieve.

Comment: No, this wouldn't affect A1 in any way. Also, I've had a chance to check this in Excel since then, and it looks right. Note the four `$`s in the range, making it absolute so it doesn't change when you copy the formula to other cells.