# Is there a way to add and/or logic into the criteria field?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Using LibreOffice Calc with the expression SUMIF, is there a way to make the criteria field look for 2 types of values using *OR* logic? Or do I have to make 2 separate SUMIF's and just add them up?

```
A    B  
Joe  1  
Joe  2  
Tim  3  
Roy  4  
Tim  5  
Roy  6
```

How do I make a SUMIF to the rows for Joe and Roy so the result is 13? Basically I want it to sum IF cells in A are Joe OR Roy.

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you gave an example of your data and what you want to compute.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer.  Create a *small* data set that illustrates your problem (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  It doesn’t have to be your *real* data; it’s preferable to use dummy/test data.  Don’t use 10-digit numbers if you can make do with 2-digit numbers.  Don’t post screenshots — just type in a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](http://superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/892744/150988).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [pipe character `|` for alternative matches](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Alternative_matches_.7C_.5B....5D):

> `=SUMIF(A1:A6;"=Joe|Roy";B1:B6)`

Take care to adapt the semicola `;` depending on your localisation, and make sure that regular expressions are enabled in the settings (Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate).

Comment: thank you very very much! why is the ; necessary this time around though?

Comment: LO uses different characters to separate parts of formulas, depending on your localisation. In my case, it's a semicolon `;`, but if you're using a different localisation, this may break the formula. So, if LO doesn't accept an example formula, it's usually due to different localisation settings.

Comment: would you happen to know how to do this exact same thing, but on Google Sheets? or would you rather me open another question? i'm unfamiliar with the etiquette here><

Comment: I'm sorry, but i havent' worked with Google Sheets yet, so i can't tell about. Anyway, it's better to open a new question, but first you should check if there's some documentation about support for functions in Google Sheet.